# Complex sorting of MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently with my query that you can find below I get the following result:
[image]

What I need to get is the following result:
[image]

As you can see in my query i've tried a few different ways of sorting but for the life of me I cannot figure this one out.

Thank you in advance!

```
-- Positive SUM
SELECT 
    o.id `Order ID`,
    ic.item_count `Item Count`,
    '' `Item Amount(s)`,
    pay.fee_amount `Broker Fee`,
    '' `Restocking Fee`,
    CASE WHEN pay.tax_amount > 0 THEN pay.tax_amount ELSE '' END `Tax`,
    pay.shipping_amount `Shipping`,
    o.`amount` `Order Total`,
    o.payment_status `Payment Status`,
    o.status `Order Status`
    FROM orders o
    JOIN order_items oi ON oi.order_id = o.id
    JOIN payments pay on pay.order_id = o.id 
    JOIN (SELECT order_id, COUNT(order_id) item_count FROM order_items GROUP BY order_id) ic on ic.order_id = o.id
    LEFT JOIN payment_histories restock on restock.payment_id = pay.id AND restock.type = 'refund_restocking_fee'
    GROUP BY `Order ID`

-- Positive line items
UNION SELECT 
    o.id `Order ID`,
    ic.item_count `Item Count`,
    oi.amount `Item Amount(s)`,
    '' `Broker Fee`,
    '' `Restocking Fee`,
    '' `Tax`,
    '' `Shipping`,
    '' `Order Total`,
    o.payment_status `Payment Status`,
    o.status `Order Status`
    FROM orders o
    JOIN order_items oi ON oi.order_id = o.id
    JOIN payments pay on pay.order_id = o.id 
    JOIN (SELECT order_id, COUNT(order_id) item_count FROM order_items GROUP BY order_id) ic on ic.order_id = o.id
    LEFT JOIN payment_histories restock on restock.payment_id = pay.id AND restock.type = 'refund_restocking_fee'


-- CANCELED ITEMS
UNION SELECT 
    o.id `Order ID`,
    ic.item_count `Item Count`,
    CONCAT('(', oi.amount, ')') `Item Amount(s)`,
    '' `Broker Fee`,
    '' `Restocking Fee`,
    '' `Tax`,
    '' `Shipping`,
    '' `Order Total`,
    o.payment_status `Payment Status`,
    o.status `Order Status`
    FROM orders o
    JOIN order_items oi ON oi.order_id = o.id
    JOIN payments pay on pay.order_id = o.id 
    JOIN (SELECT order_id, COUNT(order_id) item_count FROM order_items GROUP BY order_id) ic on ic.order_id = o.id
    LEFT JOIN payment_histories restock on restock.payment_id = pay.id AND restock.type = 'refund_restocking_fee'
    WHERE o.status = 'canceled'

-- CANCELED SUM
UNION SELECT 
    o.id `Order ID`,
    ic.item_count `Item Count`,
    '' `Item Amount(s)`,
    CONCAT('(', pay.fee_amount, ')') `Broker Fee`,
    CONCAT('(', '', ')') `Restocking Fee`,
    CONCAT('(', CASE WHEN pay.tax_amount > 0 THEN pay.tax_amount ELSE '' END, ')') `Tax`,
    CONCAT('(', pay.shipping_amount, ')') `Shipping`,
    CONCAT('(', o.`amount`, ')') `Order Total`,
    o.payment_status `Payment Status`,
    o.status `Order Status`
    FROM orders o
    JOIN order_items oi ON oi.order_id = o.id
    JOIN payments pay on pay.order_id = o.id 
    JOIN (SELECT order_id, COUNT(order_id) item_count FROM order_items GROUP BY order_id) ic on ic.order_id = o.id
    LEFT JOIN payment_histories restock on restock.payment_id = pay.id AND restock.type = 'refund_restocking_fee'
    WHERE o.status = 'canceled'




ORDER BY `Order ID`, `Order Total` DESC, `Item Amount(s)` DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

When I need to do complicated sorting in MySQL I usually use a case statement.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

For example, the following will put my user at the top of the list followed by everyone else sorted alphabetically:

```
SELECT * FROM USER
ORDER BY CASE
 WHEN USER_NAME = "Gabe.Gates" THEN 1
 ELSE 2
END ASC, USER_NAME
```

Your case would probably be something like (unsure which columns are what):

```
CASE
 WHEN `Item Amount(s)` < 0 THEN 3
 WHEN `Item Amount(s)` NULL THEN 2
 ELSE 1
END ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you would get your specific results with:

```
order by coalesce(col4, 0) desc, sign(col2) desc, abs(col2) desc
```

It is unclear what the names of your columns are.

Comment: Actually you can see the names in the query, and I just figured it out as you said that: ORDER BY `Order ID`, (SIGN(`Order Total`)) DESC, `Item Amount(s)` DESC;